# Displaying loading.gif before iframe is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, gif

So I have this button that when clicked on will send you to the next slide (void(0)). The next slide is an `iframe` which is loaded only when you click on the button. 
Before the `iframe` is fully loaded, an animated GIF should show up and in turn hide after the content is fully loaded.

In my case, the GIF is never displayed. It's totally blank until the `iframe` is fully loaded. What is wrong?

Here is the script:

```html
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function hideLoading() { 
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "none"; 
        document.getElementById('edtwo').style.display = "block"; 
    } 
</script>
```

The button:

```html
<span id="nextBtn1"><a href="javascript:void(0);"
onClick='document.getElementById("edtwo").src="ed2.html";'></a></span>
```

And the next slide which includes the GIF and the iframe:

```html
<li><div id="loading"><img src="_img/loading.gif" alt="Loading"/></div>
<iframe id="edtwo" onload="hideLoading()";></iframe></li>
```

Comment: `onload="hideLoading()";` The `;` outside of the `"` should be removed or moved inside the quote next to it. Not sure why, but I've been seeing a lot of this particular minor error a lot lately. `:\`

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks,but that's just a typo. With ; removed, it would still not work. There is probably a conflict here between getElementByID used in the button and the one used in the script. I think I should include .click as a function.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your page (or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net))? Without any CSS, the "button" is unclickable, because the anchor has no contents.

Comment: I know it's a typo and won't fix the issue; I said it was a minor error. Speaking of the question at hand, I created a demo that works I think the way you're describing: http://jsfiddle.net/2mgDw/ Note, I had to update the markup, and the code that sets the `src` for the `iframe` is only meant to force the `iframe` to stay hidden for longer; it's not meant to demonstrate any part of the solution.

Comment: @Rob W: Sure. Here: http://semiconia.com/test/indexloadonclick.html   Click on the arrow under Editorial. This loads the second slide which is only a few kb. So it shouldn't take long for it to load. But it still doesn't show the GIF. I have tried with heavier iframes which take considerably longer to load, but still no sign of the GIF.

Comment: I don't see any code which causes the `loading` element to be visible. It's always hidden, because you're never setting display to `'block'` or `''`.

Comment: Hmm. Looking at your actual page in your comment above, I think the issue you're having is that the images loading isn't delaying the `iframe`'s load event. If you look at that demo I have above, you'll notice the same issue (the image actually downloads much slower than the page load completes). I think you might need to do some image preloading and possibly use some Javascript in the `iframe` to trigger a function in the parent page.

Comment: Your `iframes` in the source also all have `background:#FFF;` in the attribute list. I imagine you meant `style="background:#FFF;"`.

Comment: @RobW - I did actually see it one time.

Comment: Rob, there is a Div tag (id="loading") in the Li. It must be there when you go to the next slide until the iframe is fully loaded. and that would be when the script comes in and hide it. Isn't it?

Comment: Jared, can you please be more specific? What kind of function exactly has to be added?

Comment: In the parent page, you're using [`MM_preloadImages()`](http://semiconia.com/test/_js/swapimg.js). What this function does is try to preload all of the images indexed in `document.images`. However, from what I can tell, your `iframe` is finishing loading very quickly because it's not going to wait for the images within *it's source* to finish and fire the `iframe`'s `onload` handler. Which gives the appearance as if the `iframe` isn't "loaded", when it has finished.

Comment: As far as I know, the MM_preloadImages () can only affect the arrows. When the mouse enters the image, the pictures changes to an arrow with outer glow (see swapimg.js). It's basically a rollover function. That's why I don't see any connection.

Comment: Try [this tutorial](http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/28/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/), which explains why. `MM_preloadImages()` is an image preloader that supports the swap functionality; the reason it's included in this *ancient* swap code is that you don't want to load the "second", non-displayed images the first time it's requested (by a rollover). I'm sure you've seen pages that didn't preload, and it's ugly and distracting. So way back, Macromedia added that suite of functions to Dreamweaver to handle swaps, including preloading to improve responsiveness/performance.

Comment: yes, but the function indicates which images to preload in particular. Here only the arrows are preloaded which are part of the main page body. The slides are distinct iframes. They don't have this function in their body.

Comment: Exactly, the `iframe`s don't preload the images they contain, so the `iframe` finishes "loading" the `src`, which is an HTML document, and then the `iframe` continues to download the images. If you want to see the loading icon until the `iframe` is literally fully loaded and ready to display (including preloaded images), you have to preload the images within the `iframe` as well, preferably within the parent document...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your *iframe* is initially displayed (and moreover, added in the DOM tree). Inspite of its empty *src* attribute it will load empty page and execute *onload* event handler. So you will have your indicator hidden as a result of calling hideLoading.

As you can see in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/m6Tpk/2/) exmaple, onload triggers without clicking on link.

You can remove frame from DOM tree and add it when user clicks "Next" button or change *.style.display* to empty string (to show it) of gif loader at this time.

Comment: By "your iframe is initially displayed" you mean that it is pre-loaded? Not really. Go to the link I put just now using FF. When you click on the arrow under Editorial, you will see the webpage gets partially refreshed. Looking at the tab, you'd see the name of the website disappears and shortly afterward reappears. That means it was successfully communicating with the server.

Comment: However, if you meant that the iframe without the content is initially there. Yes and to me, there is really nothing wrong with that. The content supposedly should be loaded, not the iframe. Since the Div tag (containing the loading.gif) comes before this iframe in the Li, the worst scenario is that it pushes the invisible iframe down and if the overflow in the parent Div tag is set to hidden, nothing would go wrong.

Comment: Currently when page loads it also loads an iframe content (which is empty page because of empty or non-set *src* attribute). This triggers onload event and hides a loader. So it becomes hidden by the time page is loaded (user even haven't clicked anything).

Comment: The `onload` on the `iframe` still fires when the link is clicked, running the `hideLoading()` handler.

Comment: So what do you suggest? (In a noob-friendly manner please. :D I'm not really a programmer).

Comment: The simpliest way is to reset *.style.display* of loader when user clicks "Next". To do this just add `document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "";` after `document.getElementById("edtwo").src="ed2.html";`

Comment: YES! It worked. Although if the slide is too light weight (like the second one here which is only a few kb) you won't see anything, but in principle, you were right. Thanks.